# JavaFX get resource (.css)

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application with an Javafx GUI.

I cant get a css which isnt in the same packet then the controller to load :/
My packet structure
[image]

the simple resoruce code .tried both and tried variants with / and ../:

[image]

Comment: Use your file explore to look at the folder structure. It may be main/resource/css/Finance.css.

Answer (score 1):

Your resources folder is way back under main, so ../ only gets you back to finance

Package directory structure looks like this

java.de.matt.finance

is actually

java/de/matt/finance

The solution I would use is to move your resources package into the finance package and use ../resources/

Or (if I counted correctly)

../../../../../../resources (basically bump to parent for each directory above it, might have to re-count it)

But the other option is kind of annoying IMO

I can't remember where the root is for getResource but you may be able to do /main/resources as well or something to that effect

I should add that you have resource listed in your code example and not resources, make sure to switch that to the correct one as well

Comment: isnt the normal way to got code under main/java/com/cmpany/apllication/... and resources under main/resources ?

Comment: I chnged it to this way now: it works in eclipse, but as exported jar it cant find it(atleast it stops working there) http://www.youscreen.de/aozptxdvt79.jpg http://www.youscreen.de/mysvylmel79.jpg any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

what about using :

```
...(getClass().getResource("/css/Finance.css").toExternalForm());
```

Check this document [accesing resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)